# How to pass a huge json file to the Command.cs in forge api design automation for revit?

Tags: autodesk-forge, revit, autodesk-designautomation

I created a project from this [tutorial](https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/tutorials/modifymodels).

How may I send a huge json file by user to be read in `Command.cs` in Design Automation for Revit on cloud? I receive the file in `DesignAutomationController.cs` using form, but i am unable to send it to `Command.cs` as in this the url becomes way too huge.

```cs
XrefTreeArgument inputJsonArgument = new XrefTreeArgument()
{
    Url = "data:application/json, " + ((JObject)inputJson).ToString(Formatting.None).Replace("\"", "'")
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How huge is the json file? The workitem payload limit is only 16 kb.

We recommend embedded json only for small contents. For anything big, you may upload the json content to a cloud storage and pass the signed url to the file as input argument URL.

Design Automation API limits are defined here:

https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/developers_guide/quotas/

Comment: I thought a DA4R app has no network or Internet access during work item execution. How can it grab the uploaded JSON data from the URL if it has no network access?

Comment: @JeremyTammik - The signed url to the JSON file would have to be provided at the time of posting the workitem. It is then similar to how one provides the input rvt file.